# Pinch, Pan, and Rotate Image view Simultaneously like Instagram story using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, instagram, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to make image view that work like instagram story post view. i have add UIPinchGestureRecognizer, UIPanGestureRecognizer and UIRotationGestureRecognizer gesture on UIImageView. Now i want to make that all gesture work at same time like instagram story post view.

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/twomedia/TMImageZoom

If still you are looking for implementations part, please check following link:

https://blog.usejournal.com/ig-pinch-drag-swift-4-390da4f86ead

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for answer. but it's not fulfill my requirement.

Comment: What is your requirement, that is not fulfilled by above links?

Answer (score 0):

Inherit UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, set gestures delegate to the view controller.

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, 
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool{
    return true
}
```

read details here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624208-gesturerecognizer